Multiple runners in WDIO with ALL tests in each runner
Trying to run multiple tests in parallel workers with wdio 9.0.9 and cucumber
We recently migrated our test project to use wdio 9 and after that after executing the following command:
npx wdio wdio.conf.js  --spec=path/to/test1 --spec=path/to/test2
2 workers are raised (which is OK) but both tests are executed in the both workers.
With the previous version of wdio it was 1 test per worker, which is the expected by me behavior.
Is the approach changed in wdio9 or I am doing sth wrong?
